# What is the story of Kolahala, Halahala and Sanda-Marka battles?

Tags: identification-request, war

Some Puranas states that there are totally 12 major Devasura battles, somewhat from Brahmanda Purana:-

> 73. The first battle was fought by Narasiṃha (originating from the Man-lion incarnation of Viṣṇu). The second one (by) Vāmana (originating from the incarnation as a Dwarf). The third one is Varāha (originating from the Boar-incarnation of Viṣṇu) and the fourth battle (took place at the time of churning of the ocean of milk for the sake of nectar.
> 74. The fifth battle was a terrible one named Tārakāmaya caused by the abduction of Tārā by Candra. The sixth of those battles was (known as) the Āḍībaka and Traipura war is remembered as the seventh.
> 75. Andhakāra is the eighth one among them. Dhvaja is remembered as the ninth. Vārtra (pertaining to Vṛtra) is the tenth horrible battle. Halāhala is remembered as the battle thereafter (i.e. the eleventh).
> 76. Kolāhala, another terrible battle is remembered as the twelfth among them.

However, "Sanda-Marka" also added as 12th battle.

> In the course of Avabhṛtha (valedictory bath after a sacrifice) Ṣaṇḍa and Marka were conquered by the Devas (and therefore the Daityas too were conquered).

Most of us know about first ten Devasura battles. But, What is the story of Kolahala, Halahala and Sanda-Marka battles?